# Mac Book Pro Wifi Not Working On Debian

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, debian

Installed Debian on Virtualbox in my mac book pro (late 2013). Debian is always showing wired connectivity. It is not showing any wireless devices.

The output of lspci is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

And the above output doesn't contain the wireless device. My macbook pro has broadcom BCM43xx series WiFi airport.

The ifconfig output is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:5e:33:3e  
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe5e:333e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:798 (798.0 B)  TX bytes:8863 (8.6 KiB)

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1200 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1200 (1.1 KiB)
```

The iwconfig output is:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Why does Debian not show the WiFi device? Please help me fix this.

Comment: Not enough for an answer (if someone wants to take this and make an answer out of it, feel free to!), but you probably need the `b43` driver and associated firmware tools. See https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/PageFragmentBroadcomBCM432x and https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx for a start. Here is the Debian Wiki search I used to find these pages: https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=broadcom&fullsearch=Text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use wireless in a VM.

Debian doesn't "see" the wireless device because there isn't one. The whole point of a virtual machine is that you do not have access to the hardware.

Comment: You are right. I need a separate wireless card for the vm. I am purchasing the tp-link wireless usb adapter. Thank You.